# Rename [ultimate-mvc3] to [ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I propose renaming the tag for Ultimate Marvel vs Capcom 3 from [ultimate-mvc3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-mvc3) to [ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I renamed the tag to [ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3).